# Como restar valores en un array (PHP)?

Tags: php, html, array, funciones, bucle-for

Primero genero un array de 3 posiciones con numeros aleatorios, despues busco restar los tres valores del array. El problema es que si la primera resta me da un numero negativo el siguiente valor no me lo resta bien.
Por ejemplo:
$dado=[6,4,4]
La resta seria: 6-4-4 = -2
Pero al ejecutarlo la resta me da: 6

Mi codigo:

```
for($i=0;$i<=2;$i++){

             $dado[]=rand(1,6);
             echo $dado[$i].' | ';
        }
$resta=0;

    for($i=0;$i<=2;$i++){
             if($dado[$i]>=0){
             $resta=$dado[$i]-$resta;
             }elseif($dado[$i]<0){
             $resta=$dado[$i]+$resta;        
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenías un fallo de planteamiento. Te pongo tu código modificado para que funcione y a continuación de este te comento:

```
for($i=0;$i<=2;$i++){
        $dado[]=rand(1,6);
        echo $dado[$i].' | ';
    }

    $resta=$dado[0];

    for($i=1;$i<=2;$i++){
        if($dado[$i]>=0){
            $resta=$resta-$dado[$i];
        }elseif($dado[$i]<0){
            $resta=$dado[$i]+$resta;        
        }
    }

    echo '<br />';
    echo 'La resta es: ' . $resta;
```

El valor de `$resta` debe empezar valiendo como el primer número de tu tirada de dados, ya que es a este número al que deseas restarle el siguiente. Por eso mismo, el bucle `for` con el que efectúas la resta debe comenzar desde la posición 1 en vez de la 0.

También tenías mal la operación en la que calculabas la resta y se la asignabas a `$resta`. El dado es el que debe restarse al valor de `$resta` y no al contrario. Recuerda que el orden de los operandos en el caso de la resta si que afecta al resultado.

Answer (score 0):

Esta comprobación sobra:

```
 $dado[$i] >= 0
```

El valor aleatorio, está entre 1 y 6, por lo tanto siempre va a ser mayor que 0.

Está mal planteado.
Añado el planteamiento correcto y comentarios para que veas que hace cada linea.

```
for($i=0;$i<=2;$i++){
    $dado[]=rand(1,6); // Ejemplo de valores obtenidos [6,4,4]
    echo $dado[$i].' | ';
}

$resta=$dado[0]; // Obtener el primer numero (6)

for($i=1;$i<=2;$i++){ //recorrer el array empezando por los valores que se van a restar; [4,4]
    $resta -= $dado[$i]; // restar los valores -4 y -4
}

echo '<br />';
echo 'La resta es: ' . $resta; //resultado -2
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. De esa forma si funciona correctamente.